# Why my TypeORM can't connect database in product mode?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am using `Nest.js`+`TypeORM` to develop and try to deploy in my computer.

I can connect to mysql in `develop mode`, but it failed in `product mode`.

Below is my TypeORM config.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    ClassificationModule,
    ArticleModule,
    UserModule,
    CommentModule,
    FragmentModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      // logging: ["query"],
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: '123456',
      database: 'myblog',
      entities: ['src/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true
    })
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In `develop mode`, it can connect to mysql successfully.

[image]

But in `product mode`, it shows can't connect mysql.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ts-node` manages your typescript compilation in memory and handles chaning references from `src` to `dist` internally. However, this is a problem when you get into running your pure `node` variant, as you'll be in a `dist` directory instead of `src`, so TypeORM won't be able to find your entities with the defined entities array. Instead you should use `entities: [join(__dirname, '/**/*.entity.{js,ts}')],` to allow for dynamically changing between ts and js so you don't have to worry about what you are running with.

I would also suggest using `tsc-watch` for develpoment, as it will run `node` by default on successful compilation and you won't have to worry about memory consumption from `ts-node`.

Comment: I am running into very similar issue, but the error doesn't show an entities issue rather a generic:
```
ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1195:16)
```

Any leads?